# How do I get DebuggerBrowsable RootHidden to work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, .net-3.5

I read about the DebuggerBrowsable attribute yesterday, and it sounded great, however when I tried to get it to work in a test, It doesn't seem to make any difference. I am using VS 2008 version 9.0.30729 1 SP, .Net 3.5 SP1, MSTest framework

```
    [TestClass]
    public class TestingDebuggerBrowsable
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void JustToDemonstrateDebugging()
        {
            var foo = new MyExposedClass();
            foo.ToString(); // I put a breakpoint here, and debugged the test
        }

    }

    public class MyExposedClass
    {
        public MyExposedClass()
        {
            ShouldBeSeeingThisInMyDebugger = new List<string> {"foo", "bar"};
        }

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]
        public IList<string> ShouldBeSeeingThisInMyDebugger { get; set; }
    }
```

When I hover over foo, I get the usual  Representation of List , where I have to drill down a few levels to get to the elements, no different than if I omitted the attribute.

I was hoping to just hover my mouse over the ShouldBeSeeingThisInMyDebugger property, and see the elements of the collection.

EDIT:
It seems that this is working on Jeroen's machine, but not mine, despite using the same IDE and framework. I'd be interested to hear if anyone else has the same problem as me.

Answer (score 2):

With the attribute added you get:

```
foo                                               {Sample.MyExposedClass}
    [0]                                           "foo"
    [1]                                           "bar"
  Raw View
```

Without the attribute you get:

```
foo                                               {Sample.MyExposedClass}
    ShouldBeSeeingThisInMyDebugger                Count = 2
        [0]                                       "foo"
        [1]                                       "bar"
  Raw View
```

So with the attribute `ShouldBeSeeingThisInMyDebugger` is omitted (the root is hidden). Just as the attribute says.

Comment: You're decribing what I was hoping to see, but not what I'm getting. Are you using the same version of IDE and framework as me? In my debugger adding the attribute makes NO DIFFERENCE to what I see.

Comment: I am running VS 2008, version 9.0.30271.1 SP, Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP 1.

Comment: Curious. Well +1 for trying anyway, there must be some mysterious difference to my build setup or something that's stopping it working on my machine

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerbrowsablestate.aspx) it says RootHidden will only hide the root element and expands the child items to show when you hover over it -

here is another link to explain what each attribute does -

http://www.dev102.com/2009/04/09/debuggerdisplay-and-debuggerbrowsable-two-debugger-attributes-you-should-know/