# What does it take for my class to show up in the Watch window as an indexed list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want my class to show up this way:

[image: screenshot]

But is showing as the `liveSelect` above instead. Here is my class' declaration:

```
public class LiveSelect<TSource, TResult> : ReadOnlyBindingList<TResult>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
{
    //...
}
```

`ReadOnlyBindingList` implements `IBindingList`. What am I missing?

**Update:** Based on 280Z28's answer, where is how I solved it:

```
internal sealed class CollectionDebuggerView<T>
{
    readonly ICollection<T> c;

    public CollectionDebuggerView(ICollection<T> col)
    {
        this.c = col;
    }

    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]
    public T[] Items
    {
        get { return c.ToArray(); }
    }
}
```

Then, have my `ReadOnlyBindingList<TResult>` class implement `ICollection<T>` and add a few attributes so that it looks like this:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Count={Count}")]
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(CollectionDebuggerView<>))]
public abstract class ReadOnlyBindingList<TResult> : IBindingList, IList, IEnumerable, IEnumerable<TResult>, ICollection, ICollection<TResult>
{
    //...
}
```

Note that `CollectionDebuggerView` needs to take in the constructor something that `ReadOnlyBindingList` implements (such as `ICollection<T>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon [another Stack Overflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683571/how-do-i-get-debuggerbrowsable-roothidden-to-work), it seems my initial suggestion of trying a [`[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerbrowsableattribute.aspx) attribute on the indexer property may not work.

You need to add the [`DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute.aspx) to your class, and configure the type proxy to expand members of an indexer.

For an example, look at the [implementation of `List<T>`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs) in Mono, which uses the [`CollectionDebuggerView<T>` debugger type proxy](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/CollectionDebuggerView.cs) for exactly this purpose.

Comment: I'm trying this but keep getting an `Entry point was not found ":"` error in the Watch view.

Answer (score 0):

if you expand the `Results View` from `liveSelect`

you should see the same thing from `someList`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an [index property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that takes an `integer`.